# Timer/countdown with custom duration?

Tags: python, timer, discord, discord.py

This chunk of code is a timer with a set duration of 90 seconds, using the command '!t90' to start.

How would I write the option to use command '!t' with any number of seconds?

(or 30, 45, 60, 90, 120 in one file (as these are the only timers that my server will use 99.9% of the time))

Thanks

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
  import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
counter_channel = None
task = None

async def ex(message):

global counter_channel
if counter_channel is not None:
    await bot.send_message(
        message.channel,
        embed=discord.Embed("There is a counter in {}".format(counter_channel.mention), color=discord.Color.red() ))
    return

counter_channel = message.channel
await bot.send_message(message.channel, "1:30")
await asyncio.sleep(30)
await bot.send_message(message.channel, "1:00")
await asyncio.sleep(30)
await bot.send_message(message.channel, "0:30")
await asyncio.sleep(20)
await bot.send_message(message.channel, "0:10")
await asyncio.sleep(10)
await bot.send_message(message.channel, "time")
counter_channel = None

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def t90(ctx):
global task
task = bot.loop.create_task(ex(ctx.message))

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def cancel(ctx):
global task, counter_channel
await bot.send_message(message.channel, "timer reset")
task.cancel()
task = None
counter_channel = None


bot.run('###token###')
```

Comment: You should fix your indentation, it's tough to tell what's in some of your coroutines.  One option would be to take the number of seconds as an argument: `async def t(ctx, seconds: int)` and then pass that number to your helper coroutine

Comment: @PatrickHaugh thank you for the fast reply, I added in `async def t(ctx, seconds: int)` and `seconds:int = [30,45,60,90,120]`. This allows me to use the commands listed but how do I change countdown - as it still calls 1:30 on every command

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could make such a command

```
from datetime import timedelta
from asyncio import sleep

def time_repr(td: timedelta) -> str:
    "Time formatter with optional dates/hours"
    minutes, seconds = divmod(int(td.total_seconds()), 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    days , hours = divmod(hours, 24)
    res = f"{minutes:>02}:{seconds:>02}"
    if hours or days:
        res = f"{hours:>02}:" + res
    if days:
        res =  f"{td.days} days, " + res
    return res

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def countdown(ctx, seconds: int):
    td = timedelta(seconds=seconds)
    while True:
        await bot.say(time_repr(td))
        if td.total_seconds() > 30:
            td -= timedelta(seconds=30)
            await sleep(30)
        elif td.total_seconds > 10:
            td -= timedelta(seconds=10)
            await sleep(10)
        elif td.total_seconds > 1:
            td -= timedelta(seconds=1)
            await sleep(1)
        else:
            break
```

Note that this won't always make the best timer: `sleep(10)` guarantees the event loop will wait *at least* 10 seconds, but it may wait longer. It'll usually be pretty close though.